# Am I using the time profiler instrument correctly?

Tags: objective-c, ios, instruments

I have a drawing application that I'm working on for the iPad.  I'm trying to speed up my drawing, so I was running some tests with the time profiler instrument.  However, I'm either doing something wrong or the time profiler just isn't going to be helpful in this situation.

What I'm looking for is basically a line by line execution time for the code that is doing my drawing.  What I got instead is below.  Basically, the time profiler says "you're spending a lot of time drawing".  My response is "Oh rly!?".  Am I using the profiler correctly, or is there a way to get it to display line by line execution times (which would be much more useful than the current output)?

[image: Screenshot of time profiling tool]

[image]

Edit:  Above, you can see more what I'm looking for. Line by line execution times.  That is not MY code, just an example of how I want/expect the time profiler to work.

Edit2:  Can you only see method by method execution times when running on the simulator?  I just tried profiling on the simulator and the output is exactly what I would expect.  However, I was really hoping for more accurate profiling using the device :(

Comment: What method or function is your drawing code in?

Comment: Most of it is in - (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context, which is passed a context from my drawRect method for one of my views.  To clarify, the 3rd image I included is not my code, it is just the type of execution time display I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time profiling tool does not seem to behave the same on the device as in the simulator.  The simulator version allows me to see line by line execution times, where as when profiling on the device, I only get output above, which is far less useful.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you cannot achieve this with time profiler, as it gathers lots of samples and unifies them to show, where you spend time the most.

You might have a solution for this task using some "raw" *dtrace* scripting. Or, you can write a sampling code based around `mach_absolute_time` ([this QA](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1398/_index.html) might be useful to convert the values to more meaningful data later on).

Comment: Good thinking about using mach_absolute_time.  I'll keep that in mind as a backup.  However, as you can see in my last image above, I know it's POSSIBLE to get line by line run times, but maybe not in my particular case for some reason.

Comment: Tried to select your method? It should be available in the right pane somewhere in stack trace.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I don't see it anywhere in the pane... *shrug*

Comment: The screenshot of assembly code is what I get when I inspect the [UIView drawInLayer] method that is taking up all the time.

Answer (score 0):

To get the line by line execution times you want, you must double-click on a function that you wrote in the call tree. In your screenshot you double-clicked a UIView method, which Apple wrote. You're getting disassembly because it's Apple's code, not yours.

If you want to focus on your code in the call tree, select the Hide System Libraries checkbox, which is just above the Show Obj-C Only checkbox you selected in your screenshot. Hiding system libraries makes it easier to find your code in the call tree, which will help you get to the line by line execution times.

Comment: If I check "Hide System Libraries", but leave Show Obj-C Only checked also, nothing appears in the call tree.

Comment: Updated my question.  I was able to see method by method when profiling the simulator, but is this possible on the device?

Comment: I don't normally select the Show Obj-C Only checkbox. Does something appear in the call tree if you deselect the Show Obj-C only checkbox? I can't verify if you can get line by line results on the device because Xcode 4.4 won't let me profile with the Time Profiler instrument on a device running iOS 5.1.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't see any methods calls to look at like I do when profiling the simulator.

Comment: You could try selecting the Hide Missing Symbols checkbox instead of the Hide System Libraries checkbox and see if that changes things.

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck.  I'm sort of convinced that the time profiler doesn't work the same on the device compared to in the simulator.